# Referral Rewards implementation Firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

I am developing a camera app that uses opencv to image processing. I uses admob to earn money for myself. I want to promote my app using referrals. Since i already using Firebase as the backend to authenticate and as the database i thought to use Firebase to do that too.

So i'm using Firebase Dynamic Links. Docs Don't give me enough details. So i just implemented the way i understood it.

```
DynamicLink dynamicLink=FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                    .setLink(Uri.parse("https://youtube.com"))
                    .setDynamicLinkDomain("https://un3v9.app.goo.gl")
                    .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
                    .buildDynamicLink();
            Uri dynamicLinkUri=dynamicLink.getUri();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),dynamicLinkUri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("gdfkjdgfsdbflkdjgidkiskgfbj",dynamicLinkUri.toString());

            Intent intent=new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder("Free Snaps")
                    .setMessage("awesome app")
                    .setDeepLink(dynamicLinkUri)
                    .build();
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_INVITES);
```

This is how i'm going to send invitations like this. Since the app is still in the development there are no link to redirect the invited people to play store so i used Youtube.com to test the dynamic links are working.

In the Firebase console,

For
setup your short URL Link -> https://un3v9.app.goo.gl/ZjWo
setup your Dynamic Link -> https://youtube.com Dynamic Link Name -> YouTube Testing
Define link behavior for iOS -> open the link URL in browser
Define link behavior for android -> open deep link URL in a browser

When i  run the code it shows an interface to send the invites. And it sends the invitation successfully.

When i open my eamail it says xxxxxx@gmail.com via unified-notifications.bounces.google.com install this app

When i clicked the link on pc or android device it goes to google play store and says item not found..

My Question is why it is not redirecting to the youtube.com
When i finally launch the app to the play store where should i put the google playstore link in my code?

Comment: Can you get a long link (from the console)  and try using the debugging view (append &d=1 at the end) so check the set up is OK?

Comment: Can you explain how to get the Long link from the console?